# Can we run multiple deep learning models on Raspberry Pi3 with TensorflowLite for inferenc

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have multiple deep learning model (say 2) and output of those is input of another deep learning model. I wannna to run this on Raspberry Pi3 for inferencing.

Can its possible to run multiple model simultaneously on device. I am using TensorFlow Lite for optimization and inferencing.

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: Did you already try to run the models in your raspberry pi 3?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro No, I have not tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is YES. For example, in [lable_image for TFLite](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/label_image.md), your input bitmap image is feed into a simple op (resize bilinear) to resize it, and the output of the simple op is then set as the output of the input of the model you specified.